# Function and Boundedness

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

If $f(x)$ is defined for all $x$, what are the conditions on $f(x)$ to make $\frac1{f(x)}$ be bounded for all $x$?

I am not entirely sure what other conditions there could be besides $f(x)$ not being $0$ and limit of $f(x)$ not reaching $0$ anywhere.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets set $g(x) = \frac{1}{f(x)}$.  Then we need to find conditions on $f(x)$ that ensure $g(x)$ is bounded.  First, we must assume that $f(x) \neq 0$ for any $x$, since otherwise $g$ would not be defined.

Now, $g$ is bounded if there is some $N > 0$ such that $|g(x)| < N$ for all $x$.  This is equivalent to $|\frac{1}{g(x)}| = |f(x)| > |\frac{1}{N}|$ for all $x$.

From this we see that $f$ must be $bounded$ $away$ from $0$.  In other words, $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is bounded if and only if there is some $N > 0$ such that $|f(x)| > \frac{1}{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

There should esist such $l < 0 < r$, that ether $f(x) < l$ or $f(x) > r$ for an arbitrary $x$.

If, for example, there is not such $r$, then $f(x)$ limits to $0$ from the right and $\frac1{f(x)}$ is inbounded above. The same for $l$.

If nevertheless, they exist, then either $0> \frac1{f(x)} > \frac1l $ or $0 < \frac1{f(x)} < \frac1r$ is true for an $x$. So, $\frac1{f(x)}$ will be bounded.